# Bootstrap buttons and input on one row while input stretching to fill space horizontally?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble trying to align Boostrap buttons and input on one line, having the input stretching horizontally while snuggling against the buttons.

Here are different attempts:
[image: Button & Input alignment]

**In case #1:** button group and input group are in the same column. The input stretches horizontally but it is thrown on the next line.

```
<h2>#1</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
```

**In case #2:** button group and input group are in two equal columns, but there's a gap between the two.

```
<h2>#2</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

**In case #3:** more column is given to the input group (ratio 3:9), but then half of the button group gets thrown to the next line.

```
<h2>#3</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">

            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

**In case #4:** button group and input group are in the same column, wrapped in an in-line form. Cozy setting, but the input doesn't stretch its feet any more.

```
<h2>#4</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

**Ideal case:** button group and input group share the same line as in #2 and are close together as in #4. In case the screen would be re-sized, I would expect the input to stretch first, before the line gets broken with divs thrown to the next line.

But how can I achieve that? Am I using the wrong forms / layout? Or does the CSS have to be modified to create a new kind of layout?

Comment: case#4, add custom style to input, `display:inline, width:100%`

Comment: Even better would be providing some code so we can debug your cases...

Comment: @shehary I couldn't make what you suggested work.

Comment: @Benjamin the above suggested solution was a guess but you can check the answer with fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML (case-4)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                </div><!-- /btn-group -->
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </form>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

With bootstrap 3.0.2

Additional CSS

```
.btn-group {
        display: inline !important;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h3r3wef6/)

With Bootstrap 3.3.5

```
.btn-group {
        display: inline !important;
}
.form-inline .input-group {
    display: flex;
}
.form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn {
    display: flex;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h3r3wef6/1/)

Comment: You should try to favor using more specific css selectors rather than `!important`

Comment: @Takendarkk you are right but it's OP's choice. my answer just to show him how he can achieve what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Takendarkk Could you please explain about the `!important`? Because I don't know about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin `!important` rule is just to over ride the existing CSS selector with your CSS property and what @Takendarkk suggested is to use more specific CSS selector means `btn-group` is existing class in bootstrap so it will be better if you create new class in CSS like `my-btn-group` and add it in HTML `<div class="btn-group my-btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">` so this way no need to modify the bootstrap css and what ever changes you make in `my-btn-group` will override the `btn-group` selector

Answer (score 1):

Use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to let the input grow to take up the rest of the available space:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

input {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-12 flex">
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
    <button>button 3</button>
    <button>button 4</button>
    <input type="text">
    <button>button 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Erm, okay that does the trick it seems, however, does that mean I do not use Bootstrap rows and columns in combination?

Comment: You can use this next to bootstrap. If all your buttons and the input are in a col-* container, just add the flex-class without the width-property to the col-* container.

Comment: So that would be `class="col-sm flex"` ?

Comment: Correct. I updated the snippet to show an example :)

Comment: Ah, it works for individual buttons and inputs, however it doesn't work with button groups and input groups.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider something like this or it may get you to where you need to be esp since it takes mobile viewports into account.

Open it up the page to full-width and reduce it.

```css
#myForm .group-change .form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #myForm .group-change {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
  }
  #myForm .group-change .input-group-btn .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #myForm .group-change .input-group-btn .btn-last {
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #myForm .group-change .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn,
  .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group {
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #myForm .group-change .dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #myForm .group-change .input-group-btn>.btn+.btn {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #myForm .group-change .btn {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="myForm"> <span class="input-group group-change">
            <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sample</button>
            </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myInput" placeholder="Text"> <span class="input-group-btn" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-last dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button">Drop <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    </span>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: When I run this, the input field doesn't stretch though.

Comment: Based on your fourth image and "ideal case" it wasnt clear if you actually wanted this to be full width. See update.

Comment: You're welcome! And if the solution works please mark it as answered so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't picked up my favorite answer yet :)